# how i can count members in python i need full code

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord, discord.py

i want to count members in discord but how
using async
       `await message.channel.send(f"""# of Members: {id.member_count}""")`
i try

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    #id = client.get_guild(ID)

    if message.content.find("!hello") != -1:
        await message.channel.send("Hi") 
    elif message.content == "!users":
        await message.channel.send(f"""# of Members: {id.member_count}""")
```

i know this is copy code my code is

```
@bot.command()
async def countmember(ctx):
    ctx.guild.members
    len(ctx.guild.members)
    await ctx.send(f""" of member: {id.member_count}""")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the amount of members from a guild can be retrieved with `member_count`, with this  you also need to properly define `guild` or just simply using `ctx.guild.member_count`

This is an example in your command, I would also recommend to use a command instead of an `on_message` event to use as a command, there's just loss of benefits using that way.

```
@bot.command()
async def countmember(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    await ctx.send(f"Member count: {guild.member_count}")
```

Even if you still wanted to get the guild count with an `on_message`, it can be done this way,

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    guild = message.guild
    if message.content.find("!hello") != -1:
        await message.channel.send("Hi") 
    elif message.content == "!users":
        await message.channel.send(f"""# of Members: {guild.member_count}""")
```

You have also used `bot` and `client` you should only be using one but i'd assume your code works